# UWP - ListView Grouping with CollectionViewSource for Collation of Collections

Tags: listview, uwp, collectionviewsource

I have a collection of objects where each object has a child collection. Top level objects are displayed in a GridView.

The child collection of each object is displayed in a ListView. This needs to be groupped.

I have found a number of examples where one collection is groupped using the CollectionViewSource static page resource - how ever I'm strugling to achieve somethign similar where there are multiple CollectionViewSources

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm new to UWP developement.

Comment: I would try creating a new UserControl that would hold your view for your list, and then the UserControl can hold the CollectionViewSource

Comment: Thanks for the comment - i was hoping there'd be a way to setup the collectionviewsource under the ListView.Resources or somewhere similar

Comment: This is "similar". It keeps all of your ItemTemplate view code in one place